# How to set Material UI Slider's initial position of valueLabel / tooltip?

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I have a slider with styled tooltip / value label set to display at the bottom:

```
function ValueLabelComponent(props) {
  const { children, open, value } = props

  return (
    <StyledTooltip open={open} placement='bottom' title={value}>
      {children}
    </StyledTooltip>
  )
}
```

[image]

However when the page is initially rendered, the tooltip is pushed above the slider as it doesn't fit beneath due to scrolling:

[image]

The position is decided by internal scripting of transform: translate property of the element.

Is there a way to turn-off this behavior so that the tooltip would always be displayed beneath the slider?